# Elasticsearch/Kibana shows the wrong timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I transfer logfiles with filebeat to elasticsearch.
The data are analyzed with kibana.

Now to my problem:
Kibana shows not the timestamp from the logfile.
Kibana shows the time of the transmission in @timestamp.

I want to show the timestamp from the logfile in kibana.
But the timestamp in the logfile is overwritten.

Where is my fault?
Has anyone a solution for my problem?

Here a example from my logfile and the my filebeat config.

```
   {"@timestamp":"2022-06-23T10:40:25.852+02:00","@version":1,"message":"Could not refresh JMS Connection]","logger_name":"org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000}


## Filebeat configuration
## https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/deploy/docker/filebeat.docker.yml
#

filebeat.config:
  modules:
    path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
    reload.enabled: false

filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    # The Docker autodiscover provider automatically retrieves logs from Docker
    # containers as they start and stop.
    - type: docker
      hints.enabled: true

filebeat.inputs:
  - type: filestream
    id: pls-logs
    paths:
      - /usr/share/filebeat/logs/*.log
    parsers:
      - ndjson:


processors:
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ['http://elasticsearch:9200']
  username: elastic
  password: 

## HTTP endpoint for health checking
## https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/http-endpoint.html
#

http.enabled: true
http.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Thanks for any support!

Comment: Can you show the file you're loading as well as your filebeat configuration?

Comment: Can you update your question as it's more legible than in comments

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the question, this could be one potential option, which would be to use filebeat processors. What you could do is write that initial @timestamp value to another field, like event.ingested, using the following script below:

```
  #Script to move the timestamp to the event.ingested field
  - script:
      lang: javascript
      id: init_format
      source: >
        function process(event) {
            var fieldTest = event.Get("@timestamp");
            event.Put("event.ingested", fieldTest);
        }
```

And then the last processor you write could move that event.ingested field to @timestamp again using the following processor:

```
  #setting the timestamp field to the Date/time when the event originated, which would be the event.created field        
  - timestamp:
      field: event.created
      layouts:
        - '2006-01-02T15:04:05Z'
        - '2006-01-02T15:04:05.999Z'
        - '2006-01-02T15:04:05.999-07:00'
      test:
        - '2019-06-22T16:33:51Z'
        - '2019-11-18T04:59:51.123Z'
        - '2020-08-03T07:10:20.123456+02:00'
```